# is there any way to group the object into multiple objects based on date in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

Here i am trying to group the object in multiple object based on date in javascript using map method but i am stuck in it, let me know if there is any solution of it.

```
   {orderData?.map((key,value)=>{
            <Card title={key?.courierDate} style={{ background: '#ffd0d7' }}>
                   <Card type="inner" style={{ background: '#ffe9ec' }}>
                                   {key?.courierStatus}
                   </Card> 
            </Card>                              
   }) }
```

Actual Object look like this:

```
[
        {
            "courierStatus": "Ready for Pick Up",
            "courierDate": "2022-07-30T11:50:28.758Z",
        },
        {
            "courierStatus": "Out for Delivery",
            "courierDate": "2022-07-30T18:33:01.775Z",
        },
        {
            "courierStatus": "Delivered",
            "courierDate": "2022-08-01T04:25:56.581Z",s"
        },
    ]
```

Expected Result:

```
 [[
    {
        "courierStatus": "Ready for Pick Up",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T11:50:28.758Z",
    },
    {
        "courierStatus": "Out for Delivery",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T18:33:01.775Z",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
        "courierStatus": "Delivered",
        "courierDate": "2022-08-01T04:25:56.581Z",s"
    },
  ]]
```

Comment: If you want to group by date then you're date has to be the `key` of your object.
`[{"2022-07-30": {...}, "2022-08-01": {...}]`

Comment: Can you place the outer object brackets that you want within your list before your 'courier' objects?

Comment: @dud3 well i am confused how can i make date as key of obect as i am getting the actual object and actualy object contains not date as a key , any suggestions?

Comment: yes you are right @dqhendricks i need it in form of array of arrays

Comment: @dqhendricks edited it now, please check !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive solution.
Note the date format it doesn't include leading zeros.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "courierStatus": "Ready for Pick Up",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T11:50:28.758Z"
    },
    {
        "courierStatus": "Out for Delivery",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T18:33:01.775Z"
    },
    {
        "courierStatus": "Delivered",
        "courierDate": "2022-08-01T04:25:56.581Z"
    }
];

const rarr = arr.reduce((acc, e) => {   
    const date = new Date(e.courierDate);
    const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    const mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const dd = date.getDate();
    const key = `${dd}-${mm}-${yyyy}`;

    acc[key] ? acc[key].push(e) : acc[key] = [e];

     return acc; 
}, {})

console.log(rarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

the second example is actually invalid JSON. a better structure if you want these grouped by date, may be to put them into an object, with date as the key for each array of objects. try this:

```js
const inputData = [
    {
        "courierStatus": "Ready for Pick Up",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T11:50:28.758Z",
    },
    {
        "courierStatus": "Out for Delivery",
        "courierDate": "2022-07-30T18:33:01.775Z",
    },
    {
        "courierStatus": "Delivered",
        "courierDate": "2022-08-01T04:25:56.581Z",
    },
];

const outputData = {};

inputData.forEach( item => {
    const date = item.courierDate.slice( 0, 10 );
    if ( !outputData.hasOwnProperty( date ) ) outputData[date] = [];
    outputData[date].push( item );
} );

console.log( outputData );
```

Comment: Thanks you! its worked exactly as what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Build an object with keys as "Date" and values are aggregated for the same date. Use `Object.values` to get expected output.

```js
const merge = (arr) => {
  const track = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const date = new Date(item.courierDate).toLocaleDateString();
    if (!track[date]) {
      track[date] = [];
    }
    track[date].push(item);
  });
  return Object.values(track);
};

const data = [
  {
    courierStatus: "Ready for Pick Up",
    courierDate: "2022-07-30T11:50:28.758Z",
  },
  {
    courierStatus: "Out for Delivery",
    courierDate: "2022-07-30T18:33:01.775Z",
  },
  {
    courierStatus: "Delivered",
    courierDate: "2022-08-01T04:25:56.581Z",
  },
];

console.log(merge(data));
```